# Realizar um select com count e somar

Tags: php, sql

Estou precisando realizar um select, que tragar a quantidade total de alunos matriculados por turma e empresa, só que quando for empresa `('X' e 'Y')` somar a quantidade total deles, `('D' e 'F')` também somar as quantidade total deles, for empresa. 'P' trazer quantidade total de alunos somente desta empresa e as outras empresa trazer o total das somas delas.

Realizo este `select`, através do período e á turma, que pode ser uma ou mais turmas. Porem não sei como trazer a somar total das empresas `('X' e 'Y')`  somar a quantidade total deles, `('D' e 'F')`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'quant_total', empresa, turma FROM `alunos` 
WHERE data_matricula >= '2014-01-01' AND data_matricula <= '2014-02-01' 
AND substr(turma, 1,4) IN ('AAAA') AND situacao = 'AT' 
GROUP BY empresa, turma
```

**Resultado:**

```
quant_total       |empresa       |turma     

1                 | X            | AAA
4                 | X            | BBB
4                 | X            | CCC
3                 | X            | DDD
1                 | F            | AAA
16                | D            | AAA
33                | D            | HHH
28                | D            | XXX
18                | D            | DDD
12                | P            | AAA
1                 | P            | HHH
11                | P            | BBB
14                | P            | CCC
23                | P            | ZZZ
1                 | P            | KKK
3                 | Y            | AAA
5                 | Y            | BBB
4                 | Y            | CCC
5                 | Y            | DDD
1                 | O            | BBB
```

Comment: Quando fazer um questionamento, nunca abrevie as palavras, aqui o entendimento é primordial.

Comment: Não manjo muito de SELECT, então um caminho ao meu ver seria no WHILE do PHP realizar as validações de turma, porém ainda não consegui imaginar como se surgir algo te dou um toque.

Answer (score 1):

segue uma solução usando CASE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'quant_total', 
            (case when empresa in ('X','Y') 
                  then 'GRUPO XY' else empresa end) empresa, turma 
FROM `alunos` 
    WHERE data_matricula >= '2014-01-01' AND data_matricula <= '2014-02-01' 
    AND substr(turma, 1,4) IN ('AAAA') AND situacao = 'AT' 
    GROUP BY (case when empresa in ('X','Y') 
                   then 'GRUPO XY' else empresa end), turma
```

Uma solução melhor seria criar uma coluna GRUPO na tabela de EMPRESA , poderia ser usar este campo para agrupar empresas

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem o que você precisa. Talvez a consulta a seguir ajude. Utilizei dois comandos `SELECT`, um para calcular a soma de alunos por empresa e turma e outro para calcular o total para as empresas `'D'` e `'F'`.

```sql
SELECT empresa, turma, count(*) AS 'quant_total'
FROM alunos
GROUP BY empresa, turma
UNION
SELECT empresa, 'Total' AS turma, count(*) AS 'quant_total'
FROM alunos
WHERE empresa IN ('D', 'F')
GROUP BY empresa;
```

O resultado é

```
+---------+-------+-------------+
| empresa | turma | quant_total |
+---------+-------+-------------+
| D       | AAA   |           3 |
| D       | BBB   |           3 |
| D       | CCC   |           4 |
| F       | AAA   |           3 |
| F       | BBB   |           1 |
| F       | CCC   |           2 |
| X       | AAA   |           3 |
| X       | BBB   |           3 |
| X       | CCC   |           2 |
| X       | DDD   |           1 |
| Y       | AAA   |           2 |
| Y       | BBB   |           2 |
| Y       | CCC   |           3 |
| D       | Total |          10 |
| F       | Total |           6 |
+---------+-------+-------------+
```

Sendo que a tabela `alunos` que utilizei para testar é

```
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id | nome      | empresa | turma |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Helena    | X       | AAA   |
|  2 | Davi      | X       | BBB   |
|  3 | Gabriela  | X       | CCC   |
|  4 | Laura     | X       | BBB   |
|  5 | Beatriz   | X       | AAA   |
|  6 | Enzo      | X       | CCC   |
|  7 | Valentina | X       | DDD   |
|  8 | Samuel    | X       | BBB   |
|  9 | Rafael    | X       | AAA   |
| 10 | Lucas     | Y       | CCC   |
| 11 | Gabriel   | Y       | AAA   |
| 12 | Maria     | Y       | BBB   |
| 13 | Ana       | Y       | BBB   |
| 14 | Guilherme | Y       | CCC   |
| 15 | Luiza     | Y       | AAA   |
| 16 | Heitor    | Y       | CCC   |
| 17 | Arthur    | D       | BBB   |
| 18 | Alice     | D       | BBB   |
| 19 | Bernardo  | D       | CCC   |
| 20 | Manuela   | D       | AAA   |
| 21 | Mariana   | D       | BBB   |
| 22 | Gustavo   | D       | CCC   |
| 23 | Isadora   | D       | CCC   |
| 24 | Felipe    | D       | AAA   |
| 25 | Julia     | D       | CCC   |
| 26 | Matheus   | D       | AAA   |
| 27 | Rafaela   | F       | BBB   |
| 28 | Isabella  | F       | CCC   |
| 29 | Miguel    | F       | AAA   |
| 30 | Giovanna  | F       | CCC   |
| 31 | Nicolas   | F       | AAA   |
| 32 | Pedro     | F       | AAA   |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
```

Por favor, detalhe melhor a sua pergunta se as respostas aqui apresentadas não resolverem o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Oi amigos estou refazendo minha perguntar aqui, para que compreendeste melhor.
A resposta de Motta, está quase como eu quero, porem só somou as empresas ('X','Y'), o restante do resultado que espero, mencionado abaixo não trouce, mais mesmo assim agradeço muito pela força.

A questão é, na escola existe varias turmas com alunos de diferentes empresas, dado o um determinado período e seleção de uma ou mais turmas, preciso realizar um SELECT para trazer quantidade total de alunos registrados na escola, agrupando por turma e empresa. Á logica é, se forem alunos das empresas -> ('X'  e  'Y'), empresas -> ('D' e 'F') somar a quantidade de alunos destas duas empresas, para obter um resultado único, se for alunos da empresa 'P' trazer quantidade  total de alunos somente desta empresa, e por ultimo, se forem alunos de qualquer outra empresa, somar a quantidades de alunos total destas empresas, para obter também um único resultado, tudo isto agrupado por turma e empresa.

No momento só conseguir fazer um SELECT que trás a quantidade total de alunos  agrupados por turma e empresa. Porem não sei como realizar á somar das quantidade total dos alunos das empresas ('X' e 'Y'), empresas -> ('D' e 'F'), para obter um resultado único delas.

Conseguir a Solução galera, Obrigado á todos pela ajuda.

Solução:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'quant_total', 
(CASE WHEN empresa IN ('X','Y')
THEN 'X/Y'
WHEN empresa IN ('D','F')
THEN 'D/F'
WHEN empresa = 'P'
THEN 'EMP.P'
ELSE 'OU' END) empresa, turma 
FROM `alunos` 
WHERE data_mat >= '$dt_inicio' AND data_mat <= '$dt_fim' AND substr(turma, 1,4) IN ($turma) AND situacao = 'AT' 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN empresa IN ('X','Y') 
THEN 'X/Y'
WHEN empresa IN ('D','F')
THEN 'D/F'
WHEN empresa = 'P'
THEN 'EMP.P'
ELSE 'OU' END), turma